# Is it possible to import all classes from a directory and initialise them?

Tags: javascript, import

Say this is how my directory tree looks like:

```
/
  Children/
    ChildrenIndex.js
    Base.js
    ChildA.js
    ChildB.js
    ChildC.js
    ...
    ChildN.js

  Main.js
```

Where any given `ChildX.js` looks like this,

```js
import Base from './Base.js';

class ChildX extends Base {
  constructor(params) {
    this.params = params
  }
}

export default ChildX
```

And `ChildrenIndex.js` looks like this,

```js
export {default as ChildA} from './ChildA.js';
export {default as ChildB} from './ChildB.js';
export {default as ChildC} from './ChildC.js';
...
export {default as ChildN} from './ChildN.js';
```

Is it possible that I can import all children of `Base.js` in `Main.js` and get a list full of instances, each of a child's initialisation? Here is the pseudo code doing what I want:

```js
import { * } from './Children/ChildrenIndex.js'

class Main {
  constructor() {
    let childConstructors = getAllConstructorsIn('./Children/ChildrenIndex.js');
    let children = [];
    for (let constrt of childConstructors) {
      children.push(new constrt(params));
    }
  }
}
```

I can manually do this with `import { ChildA, ChildB, ChildC, ... ,ChildN } from './Children/ChildrenIndex.js'` and then fill the list like this: `[new ChildA(params), new ChildB(params), new ChildC(params), ... , new ChildN(params)]`. And, that works fine. However, I want someone to be able to just put an implementation of the `Base.js` in the children directory in order to add new functionality and not have to worry about then going and writing import statements and initialisation in other parts of the code. I am doing this in the model of a React app if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in `Main.js`:

```js
import * as Children from "./Children/ChildrenIndex";

Children.ChildA // ChildA component
Children.ChildB // ChildB component
```